# Scala parallelize subsets call

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, set

I have a List from which I want to extract subsets. So I do`

```
val l = List(1,2,4).toSet.subsets.toList
```

`This works on small list sizes but fails on large lists. How to make the subsets call parallel ?

I tried making the list 'l' itself parallel, but the toSet call on that lists returns a parSeq that doesn't have a subset call. Do I have to write my own subsets algorithm ?

Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be 2 reasons why it fails:

- takes too much time to execute
- runs out of memory

Both are related to the same problem: you are trying to materialize an iterator which grows exponentially in size.

There is a good reason that `def subsets(): Iterator[Set[A]]` returns an iterator and not a list - the result set might be huge. In fact the number of
all possible subsets is `2^n`:

```
scala> (1 to 10).toSet.subsets.size
res0: Int = 1024

scala> math.pow(2, 10)
res1: Double = 1024.0
```

If you parallelize generation of subsets you will be still quickly running out of memory or waiting endlessly. In other words it's an algorithmic problem, not a concurrency/hardware problem.

The way to approach this is to consume the lazy generator (iterator/stream) as you go instead of trying to get all data at once. If you prefer `Stream` interface you can convert the returned iterator to stream:

```
scala> (1 to 10).toSet.subsets.toStream
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Stream(Set(), ?)
```

Streams are just lazy lists so there is not much difference in terms of the data structure itself and it should fit your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, I realised that this is an algorithmic issue. Using toStream didn't help much as I'm running out of memory. Thanks again, I have to take the laziness out of my programming and get better at algorithms :)

Comment: "I have to take the laziness out of my programming and get better at algorithms :". Well, the reverse, really. You need to get better at programming and put the laziness into your algorthims :)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul true that :)